# how to find time zone name from UTC time offset

Tags: c#, timezone

need to find timezone from time zone Offset.
example: localTimestamp":"2019-08-26T16:09:45.5003126+05:30.Need to find the time zone like "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles", Any Api i can use?

Comment: But there can be multiple different timezone IDs that correspond to a single offset. How do you want to choose a single one in this case?

Comment: @Sweeper highest native population and DST is used as of at the time of evaluation :P